# Inverse Fourier Transform of $1/f$

Tags: probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I was trying to answer this question: [Identity for all uniformly bdd functions follows "by basic Fourier (transform) analysis"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329381/identity-for-all-uniformly-bdd-functions-follows-by-basic-fourier-transform-a#comment4795492_2329381)
which involved:
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(1/\varphi(-\cdot)),$$
where $\varphi = \mathcal{F}(P)$, where $P$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

I noticed that using a Fourier analysis trick that I might write it as $\mathcal{F}(1/\varphi(\cdot))$ (which might not be a good idea... if it is wrong, then please tell me). So, I tried to search "Fourier transform of $1/f$" in Google, which then autocorrected to "inverse Fourier transform of $1/f$", which I thought was so strange. I then searched Google but because of formatting I did not find anything. So, I tried Wolfram Alpha did not understand what I was asking.

So, I was wondering if there is something up with this expression or what? Thanks.

---

Update: What, if any, smoothness properties of this do we know? We know by http://math.mit.edu/~jerison/103/handouts/fourierint2.13.pdf that $\varphi$ is continuous and bounded, but that doesn't look good for the function in question since it might not even be in $L^2$?

Comment: Of course in general $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\frac{1}{\varphi}]$ cannot be simplified. The Fourier transform is a linear operator, while $\varphi \mapsto \frac{1}{\varphi}$ is completely non-linear.

Comment: The exceptional case is when $\frac{1}{H(\omega)}$ is a rational function, which is how we solve linear differential equations

Comment: i don't know if this is useful or not i'm just learning FT , we can use the FT of a signum function $$\mathrm{sgn}(t) \Leftrightarrow \frac{2}{j \omega}$$ from here $$\frac{1}{f} \Leftrightarrow j \pi \mathrm{sgn}(t)$$

Comment: $f$ is an arbitrary function, not a variable. That is the confusion that Wolfram Alpha had.

Comment: You might want to make a new comment with your new question since this is an old question.